# Understanding the `green triangale by default`

Tags: meaning

From the link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988796/how-to-debug-python-in-visual-studio

I saw the commenter says:

> The green triangale by default should run python in Debug mode.

I do not understand the `green triangale by default`.

So, whats that mean there? I checked dictionary, there is no answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is referring to the Start / Run button in Visual Studio:

[image]

And by "by default" he means with the default configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Unless set otherwise "**by default**" means "*factory default settings*".

Comment: It's just missing some commas: *The green triangle, by default, should run python in Debug mode.*